# Mercurial and modifying UNIX file permissions from Windows Client

Tags: mercurial, file-permissions

I am in a particularly unique situation using Mercurial. My group is developing across some different hardware architectures running embedded Linux; as a result we do most of our code development on desktop Linux and PC's and do the builds on our servers running the various hardware architectures.

There is a scenario where someone using Windows needs to push all of their changes to the mercurial server. However, the server and all of our build machines run Linux and expect certain (UNIX) file permissions for certain types of files.

My question is this: is it possible and is there a facility for modifying UNIX file permissions from a PC or is there a way in Mercurial to setup some sort of file permission rules when adding files and pushing changes up?

Note that most PC users are using the TortoiseHG GUI or the hg command line interface.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mercurial can only track two things for a file: the executable state and the symlink state. This means that you cannot store more complex permissions (e.g., group permissions).

On Windows, Mercurial will not try to read or write the executable and symlink bits. Newly added files will thus appear as non-executable on Unix (mode 644) and as regular files. Use `hg manifest -v` to see the permissions converted back into Unix convention, but remember that Mercurial really only stores two bits per file.

It is not possible to manipulate the stored bits on Windows. There are no rule system in place for setting the bits — but an extension could be written to implement such a system.

If you need more specialized permissions on your files than this, then you will need to set them after `hg update` on your build machines. A hook could be used for this, or you could write an extension. I don't think there is an [existing extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UsingExtensions) that does this, but the extensions that save and restore the modification time on checked out files should be a good starting point.

Comment: Yeah I was wondering how the permissions were resolved from people creating files in Windows vs Linux. I found that when the Linux servers got the pushed files the OS itself gave default permissions and, like you said, only the executable state is tracked. I will look into hooks and extensions. Thanks!

Comment: @akagixxer: Exactly right, Mercurial creates new files in the working copy using a normal `open(path, 'w')` call and it's then up to the `umask` to remove things like write permissions for group and other (or not with a permissive `umask`).